# Finding the largest and the smallest in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I had an assignment, where I let users choose random numbers, and this program would find the smallest and the largest between all these numbers, and if a number is not entered it would consider it an invalid input.
Here's the code I wrote:

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
inp = raw_input("Enter a number: ")

if inp == 'done': break
if len(inp) < 1: break

try:
    num = int(inp)
except:
    print "Invalid input"
    continue

if smallest is None:
    smallest = num
elif inp < smallest:
    smallest = num

if largest is None:
    largest = num
elif inp > largest:
    largest = num

print "Maximum is %r" % (largest)
print "Minimum is %r" % (smallest)
```

The question is, why is it not working ?
Here's some random numbers I tried and got something weird.
[Here I executed the code in the first part and got weird answers, and I executed it again with different numbers and got it right.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0P7GK.png)

Comment: There's something funny going on with the indentation in your code sample; given that in Python it is significant, you should really fix it (as it is now, the Python interpreter would refuse to run it).

Comment: No no the indentations are right, I'm just new to stack overflow that's why I failed to indent some lines. :P

Answer (score 2):

You've mixed up `<` and `>` and you're comparing `inp` which is a string to `smallest` and `largest` instead of `num`.

Comment: I edited, can you check the picture I posted newly ? Thanks

Comment: Ohh yes yes, you're right, lemme change it and try again.

Comment: Alright yes it works now, thanks a lot. That was very stupid mistake. smh.

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is wrong and you made a lot of misprints. Look at this code.
In if-then-else you have to compare `num` with `smallest` and `largest` but not `inp`.

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    inp = raw_input("Enter a number: ")

    if inp == 'done': break
    try:
        num = int(inp)
    except:
        print "Invalid input"
        continue

    print num
    if smallest is None: smallest = num
    elif num < smallest: smallest = num

    if largest is None: largest = num
    elif num > largest: largest = num

print "Maximum is %r" % (largest)
print "Minimum is %r" % (smallest)
```

Comment: Yes yours works too and it is also executing the number typed. In my code, I swapped the signs and changed inp into num and it is executing successfully.